# CENTOS 7 - incrond service doesn't start properly on reboot

Tags: service, reboot, incrond

I'm having some trouble with incrond not starting properly after a reboot.

If I check the service, everything looks ok:

```
$ systemctl is-active incrond.service
active
$ systemctl is-enabled incrond.service
enabled
```

But the service isn't working - changes to monitored directories don't trigger the appropriate scripts.

If I manually restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart incrond.service
```

Everything is fine, and it works as expected ... until the next reboot.  I don't control, or usually have fore-knowledge of the reboots, so this is a real problem.

grepping through /var/log/messages around the time of the reboot I find the following:

```
/var/log/messages:1814:Aug  2 19:08:45 <hostname> systemd: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/incrond.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
/var/log/messages:2257:Aug  2 19:08:54 <hostname> audispd: node=ssa-linux-2 type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1501726134.411:86): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=incrond comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
/var/log/messages:2262:Aug  2 19:08:54 <hostname> audispd: node=ssa-linux-2 type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1501726134.411:86): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=incrond comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

I've changed the permissions, as indicated in the first line - but it says it was starting  anyway.

Suggestions?